# google spreadsheet all rows after an empty rows are undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, spreadsheet, google-api-nodejs-client

recently I started a project where I need to read some data from a Google SpreadSheet document. The problem is that in the same sheet I have multiple tables with some empty rows between them. I don't understand why every row after the first completely empty  row is "undefined".

```
var variables = require('./util/variables'); //variables used in local script.
   const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
   const { promisify } = require('util');
   const creds = require('./client_secret.json');

   async function accessSpreadsheet() {


   const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('gssReference');  //aceess the data 
   from specific gss
   await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
   const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
   const sheet = info.worksheets[0]; //access data from first sheet in gss document and save in sheet 
   variable
   const rows = await promisify(sheet.getRows)({
        offset: 0
    })
    console.log(rows.length);
}
accessSpreadsheet();
```

For example, rows.length it returns 32 witch is the length of the first table. After this table I have 2 empty rows and other table. Does anyone know why Google SpreadSheet API is working like this when find an empty row and how can I solve this problem.